# Как подключить второй css файл к определенному разделу сайта?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Можно ли как-нибудь подключить второй css файл к сайту только для определенного раздела? Например, меню слева и хеддер на всех страницах сайта одинаковые. Хочу стили этих двух элементов выделить в отдельный css файл и потом просто ссылкой добавлять его на остальные разделы.

Comment: Вообще не понял. Если меню и хедер на всех страницах одинаковые то при чем тут определенные разделы? И зачем создавать отдельные файлы?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, конечно, не понятно зачем вам это, но раз уж на то пошло, просто пропишите в head два тега link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static.css" /><!--стили для header и footer-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" /> <!--другие стили-->
```